# HttpRequest for content-length in response header

Tags: android, http-headers, google-drive-api

This HttpRequest is to Google Drive.

When I parse the response header, content-length is null.  This is true when I use the getContentLength() method (see below), and also when I print out the response header.toString -- the value isn't there.

I'm not familiar httpRequests, do I have to ask for content-length to be included in the response?

```
public static HttpResponse getFile_contents(String downloadurl, Drive drive) throws IOException{

    HttpRequest request = drive.getRequestFactory().
                buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadurl));

    HttpResponse response = request.execute();

    Long length = response.getHeaders().getContentLength();
    //Length is null...

    return response;

}
```